# Como evitar "not enough values to unpack"

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo con muchos datos
A lo que imprimo linea por linea con el siguiente codigo

```
a = open("YouTubeChannels.txt","r",encoding="windows-1252")
print(a.readline().strip().split("\t"))
for linea in a:
    print(linea.strip().split("\t"))
```

Aparece lo siguiente

```
['userID', 'name', 'uploads', 'subscribers', 'videoviews', 'country', 'channeltype', 'grade', 'YouTube_Link', 'YouTube_Link-href']
['PewDiePie', 'PewDiePie', '3779', '90210848', '20772365682', 'US', 'Entertainment', 'A', '', 'https://youtube.com/channel/UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw']
```

Entonces, confiadamente creo una funcion como la siguiente

```
def leerDatos(archivo):
a = open(archivo,"r",encoding="windows-1252")
a.readline()
dic = {}
for linea in a:
    userID, name, uploads, subscribers, videoviews, country, channeltype, grade, youTubeLink, youTubeLinkhref = linea.strip().split("\t")
    if channeltype == "":
        channeltype = "SinTipo"
    if channeltype not in dic:
        if videoviews != "0":
            dic[channeltype] = {name: [uploads, subscribers, videoviews,grade,youTubeLinkhref]}
    else:
        if videoviews != "0":
            dic[channeltype][name] = [uploads, subscribers, videoviews,grade,youTubeLinkhref]
a.close()
return dic
```

Pero me retorna el error "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 10, got 9)"
Cuando realmente si existen los 10 datos que deseo desempacar.
¿Hay forma de arreglar esto? Es decir, es lo único que me impide crear mi humilde diccionario jeje Gracias

Comment: Debajo de `for linea in a:`, imprime la lista devuelta por `split()`, y ademas el tamaño de la lista con `len(<la lista devuelta por split()>)`.
Esto es para que puedas ver cual es el registro problemático (si es que hay alguno).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de mi comentario para depurar tu código, te propongo que en lugar de obtener los nombres como lo estás haciendo, simplemente obtengas el resultado en una lista; es decir:

```
yt_info_list = linea.strip().split("\t")
```

Y esto lo puedes desempaquetar sin problemas con: `*yt_info_list`, o puedes utilizar los índices: `yt_info_list[0]`.

Si te gusta esta idea, puedes documentar tu código, tu función, para mostrar el contenido de cada valor.

Comment: Gracias, pasé tratando de arreglarlo pero, ya no dí más jajaja mañana pruebo tu solución, gracias